# How to reset video settings?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Some video settings are always re-enabled after restarting because I've used some `mat_`* commands in the past. I've deleted `video.txt` file (where video settings are seemingly stored) in  `~\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg\`, this had no effect.

Is there a command to reset video settings, as clearing configuration files appears not to work?

Comment: Have you noticed the contents of `video.txt` changing between configuring the settings and exiting the game? If so, one option is to configure the settings as you want and then make `video.txt` read-only before exiting the game.

Comment: There may be another video.txt in `Steam\userdata\yoursteamid\730\local\cfg`. Also `mat_savechanges` is a winner after you've set up everything (make sure the video file is not set to read-only).

Comment: @Mark: Values in the file change. I assume this is a bug in the game as currently only fullscreen settings is affected (resets back to fullscreen, I prefer borderless window). The file in CS:GO folder wasn't recreated, for location see dly's comment.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry, I actually was using Steam launch command `full` which forces fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Delete the cfg folder in Steam\SteamApps\common\CSGO\cfg

Step 2: Right click your game in steam library and Verify Integrity of Game Cache

Comment: Data should be backed up before deleting, most notably `autoexec.cfg`. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @user198327 What if your autoexec is part of the problem?

Comment: @JMac: I've removed all video settings commands from autoexec. I'll check after deleting the configuration files.

Answer (score -2):

Changing resolution in out game or reset video's setting

1. Click on (start) write (run)
2. Write (regedit) in run
3. Open HKEY_CURRENT_USER
4. Open Valve
5. Click on your CS
6. Click on your
7. Click on SCREENHEIGHT and SCREENWIDTH
8. Then change value data to any number you want. 800/600 is good.

If this doesnt work try this one. This one will reset your video settings.

1. Click on (start) write (run)
2. Write (regedit) in run
3. Open HKEY_CURRENT_USER
4. Open Valve
5. Delete Half-Life
6. Open your game, it resetted video setting.